# Read a data file containing multiple variables in bash

Tags: bash

I want to read the following variables from a data file in bash.

```
#/tmp/input.dat
$machie=1234-567*890ABC
$action=REPLACE
$location=test_location
```

Thanks for your help.

Tas

Comment: Do you control the input format?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, I do.

Comment: If you didn't have the leading `$`s, your input file would be a valid shell script, so you could `source /tmp/input.dat` to execute it in the current interpreter. Of course, this means you need to trust its contents to not do anything malicious (even unintentionally!) when parsed in this way; it would be safer to generate it with code that knows how to do proper shell escaping if it's not hand-written by a human who knows the pertinent rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in
  ''|[0-3].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0 or newer is required" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

# read input filename from command line, default to "/tmp/input.dat"
input_file=${1:-/tmp/input.dat}

declare -A vars=()

while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ $line = "#"* ]] && continue  # Skip comments in input
  [[ $line = *=* ]]  || continue  # Skip lines not containing an "="
  line=${line#'$'}                # strip leading "$"
  key=${line%%=*}                 # remove everything after first "=" to get key
  value=${line#*=}                # remove everything before first "=" to get value
  vars[$key]=$value               # add key/value pair to associative array
done <"$input_file"

# print the variables we read for debugging purposes
declare -p vars >&2

echo "Operation is ${vars[action]}; location is ${vars[location]}" >&2
```

---

See:

- [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) - *How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?*
- [BashFAQ #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) - *How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?*; here, we're using associative arrays, but you could use the same technique to assign directly to named variables.<sup>[1]</sup>
- [Parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), the syntax used for isolating the "key" and "value" sections of each line; also covered in [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100).

---

<sup>[1] - Note that if you *aren't* going to use associative arrays, as suggested in this answer, for security reasons it's best to use a prefixed namespace: `printf -v "var_$key" %s "$value"` -- generating variable names you would dereference as `$var_action` or `$var_location` -- is much safer than `printf -v "$key" %s "$value"`, as the former ensures that your data file can't overwrite a security-critical environment variable such as `PATH` or `LD_PRELOAD`, by way of causing such attempts to harmlessly set `$var_PATH` or `$var_LD_PRELOAD`.</sup>